# Alternative to Google Search API for Shopping for Android app

Tags: android, api, google-search-api

I am in the process of creating an App in which the user needs to be able to search for products (or if possible scan the products bar code) so that they can select a product and the app can then process the information about it (item name, descriptions, price etc).

I was planning to use the Google Search API however have just noticed its being depreciated, what would be another good method to achieve what I am wanting to do with my app.

I would prefer something that is integrated well with Android perhaps a library, or a good API could work to.

Thank you and I hope you can help!

Comment: http://shoppingapishutdown.com/ (Disclosure: I am one of the co-founders)

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Semantics3 Product API](https://www.semantics3.com). They allow UPC/EAN searches as well as free-text searches on their API. The API then returns pretty detailed information about the products including the ones you mentioned.

They do have a [Java library](https://github.com/Semantics3/semantics3-java) too so you could easily integrate it with your Android app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm representative of https://aerse.com. Aerse provides:

- Free access using API
- Clear product names, specifications and images
- Good search algorithms: "product name" + "one of the product's property name", "vendor name" + "property value" and etc.